# Reloading a DIV's image and class by Javascript on click of separate DIV.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

The code I’m working with is too long to post, so I’ve made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Emily92/5b72k225/

This code takes a random image and cuts it up into a number of pieces depending on the class that is applied in the div which contains the image.

When the page loads, a random image is selected from the array and the class is applied to it, what I’m trying to do is create a separate div, which when clicked on will reload the div containing the image. The result I’m looking for is for the image to be replaced by a new random image with the class applied to it.

Right now, the only way I can make a new image appear in the div is to reload the entire page, ideally this would be achieved by just having the div reload instead of all the other page elements reloading too.

I haven’t been able to do this so far but have received some help on here on how to reload an image and class on click of a div, lines 980-1018 of the Javascript code in the jsfiddle is the current attempt at achieving this, but solving this problem seems much more complicated as the image is being manipulated by the Javascript code, so perhaps this needs to also be reloaded at the same time as the new randomised image is selected?

This is the current attempt at solving this problem:

```
$(function() {
    var imageArray = [
    'http://www.webdesignhot.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/CatsVectorImage.jpg',
    'http://www.costume-works.com/images/halloween_cat_in_witch_hat.jpg',
    'http://onthewight.com/wp-content/2013/04/sooty-ryde.jpg'];
    reloadImages(imageArray);
    $('#reload').on('click',function(){
        $( "#masterdiv img[id^='div']" ).each(function(index){
            $(this).removeClass("jqPuzzle jqp-r"+(index+3)+"-c"+(index+3)+"-SCN");
            $(this).fadeOut( "slow", function() {
                if(index==0) {
                    reloadImages(imageArray);
                }
                $(this).addClass("jqPuzzle jqp-r"+(index+3)+"-c"+(index+3)+"-SCN");
                $(this).fadeIn();

            });
        });
    });
});


function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

function reloadImages(array){
    shuffleArray(array);
    for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
        // places the first image into all divs
        document.getElementById('div'+(i+1)+'id').src=array[0];
    }
}
```

I’ve written more details on the issue in the html section of the jsfiddle. I'd really appreciate any advice in solving this and thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin reads the images' `src` before page load, takes them and then generates the puzzle. As such, you can not just update the images as they're not there anymore. So you'd have to clear the `div`s under each difficulty classes (`easyDiv`,`mediumDiv`,`hardDiv`), append a new `<img>` under each div then calls / reload the plugin. Updated code in : http://jsfiddle.net/5b72k225/6/

Changes I've made:

1. Separate old `reloadImages` into `initImages` and `reloadImages`. `initImages` is called in the beginning, while `reloadImages` is called when reloading.
2. Created new function `makePuzzle` by taking out the intialization of the plugin from `$(document).ready()` block, so `makePuzzle` can be called after reloading new image.

The new `$(document).ready()` block now initializes the images and attaches click event handler to the button. When clicked, `div`s are emptied, new `<img>`s inserted and plugin is called.

Comment: Hi @anugerah-erlaut thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I needed, I'm going to mark it as the correct answer. I did have one question about it, I'm wondering how would I make the images fade in and fade out when they change? I thought  ``img.appendTo(divs[i]).fadeIn('slow');`` might work but it doesn't work, do you know what might work? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You can make `#masterdiv` `fadeOut` on click, reload images, and then call the plugin. Once that's done, call `fadeIn` so the new puzzle is loaded. I've updated the fiddle with the new codes (line 1014-1023), check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/5b72k225/8/